# Convert getText to extracted substring to integer value (java)

Tags: java, string, input, integer, substring

I have a code that takes the user input(a price ex. $5.99) and converts it into integer values. What I have done is I have the user input a value and there is a `getText()` to retrieve the user's input in text form. Then there is another line of code to extract the string into two separate substrings (so it can be displayed like "5 dollars" and "99 cents" in the program). Then the last piece of few lines of code converts the substrings into integer values. The problem that I am having is for some reason the code does not compile when I am running it. I do not see any syntax errors and I have searched on google for some help but I couldn't find any solutions.

I have included a snippet of my code

```
initialPrice= new Text();


userInput.setText(initialPrice.getText());
String stringInput= userInput.toString();

String subDollar = stringInput.substring(0,stringInput.indexOf('.'));
String subCent = stringInput.substring(stringInput.indexOf('.'));


int dollars = Integer.parseInt(subDollar);
int cents = Integer.parseInt(subCent)

Text finalDollars = new Text("Final amount of dollars: " + dollars);
Text finalCents = new Text("Final amount of cents: " + cents);
```

Comment: *"The problem that I am having is for some reason the code does not compile when I am running it"* -- this is confusing. Either a program compiles or it doesn't, and if it doesn't compile, then it can't be run. Please show any and all error messages that either the compiler or the JVM gives you. Help to clarify this question. You will want to go through the [help] and in particular the [ask] links too.

Comment: what do you mean with "the code does not compile when I am running it"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: `subDollar = stringInput.substring(0,stringInput.indexOf('.'));` will contain the dollar symbol and trying to parse that with `Integer.parseInt("$5");` will cause a NumberFormatException. You should change it to only get the digits before the decimal point to `substring(1,stringInput.indexOf('.'))`